# Glass Mapper t4 null or empty string

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, tds

I'm trying to setup Glass Mapper to generate my Sitecore items.  I've followed every tutorial I could find, but receive this error when attempting to generate the code:

"Loading the include file 'Helpers.tt' returned a null or empty string. The transformation will not be run."

A file is generated but repeats the word "ErrorGeneratingOutput" over and over.

Screenshots:

[image: Visual Studio error output]

[image: TDS Code Generation Settings]

[image: TDS Project setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as what Ehab has suggested, you may also have to remove the empty line at the end of `GlassV3Header.tt` otherwise you will get a error:

```
An error occured while generating code for item '/sitecore/templates'.
T4 Template: D:\Project\XYZ\TDS.Master\Code Generation Templates\GlassV3Item.tt

Errors:
Compiling transformation: Invalid token 'this' in class, struct, or interface member declaration     
Compiling transformation: Method must have a return type     
Compiling transformation: Type expected
```

Crytic, but deleting the extra line solves the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue and had to delete the extra line at the end as well as go to each line and delete the extra spaces at the end of each line.  Not sure why I had to delete the extra spaces at end of each line, but after doing that, it fixed my issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to click the unblock button in the properties window of the file?

[image: unblock]