# Sitecore TDS Code generation Error

Tags: sitecore, code-generation, glass-mapper, sitecore7.5

I am trying to generate code from TDS code Generation by following [GlassTutorial24](http://www.glass.lu/en/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial24.aspx) TDS version: 5.1.0.3, visual studio 2012.

The generated class only has "ErrorGeneratingOutput".

My project properties as below:
[image: TDS Project Properties]

Edit 1:

Error while building:

> Error 1 Compiling transformation: Metadata file
>   'HedgehogDevelopment.CodeGeneration.Extensions.dll' could not be
>   found xxx.TDS.Master\Code Generation Templates\glassv3header.tt
>
> Error 2 Compiling transformation: Invalid token 'this' in class,
>   struct, or interface member declaration xxx.TDS.Master\Code Generation
>   Templates\GlassV3Item.tt
>
> Error 3 Compiling transformation: Method must have a return
>   type  xxx.TDS.Master\Code Generation Templates\GlassV3Item.tt
>
> Error 4   Compiling transformation: Type expected xxx.TDS.Master\Code
>   Generation Templates\GlassV3Item.tt

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, can you get more details on the error from your target file?

Comment: My target file only have "ErrorGeneratingOutput" 2274 times

Comment: how about your output window from 'Team Development for Sitecore'

Comment: Make sure that the tt templates don't have any new lines or white spaces at the end of the files.

Comment: Some tips here: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/02/06/upgrade-sitecore-glass-mapper-from-v2-to-v3/ Unblock the .tt files and make sure you remove the new lines in at the end of the .tt files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Glass Mapper t4 null or empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306152/glass-mapper-t4-null-or-empty-string)

Comment: Actually no, i have unblocked .tt file and removed all new lines at the end of files. still no code is generated.

Comment: Well your original question was a dupe. If you have new or different errors please provide a stack trace. If the output window shows very little then change the build output verbosity in Visual Studio (Tools > Options > Projects > Build and Run) http://imgur.com/3oQ3rdk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the tutorial was out of date and need to be updated to the new code generation templates.

You need to use the files from Hedgehogs Repository:
https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/tds-codegen/tree/master/Sitecore.Master/Code%20Generation%20Templates

You also need the following files:

- Helpers.tt
- GlassV3Header.tt
- GlassV3Item.tt
- GeneralExtensions.tt
- Inflector.tt
- StringExtensions.tt

The tutorial has now been updated as well:

http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial24.aspx

Comment: Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'HedgehogDevelopment.CodeGeneration.Extensions.dll' could not be found xxx.TDS.Master\Code Generation Templates\glassv3header.tt

Comment: Compiling transformation: Invalid token 'this' in class, struct, or interface member declaration  xxx.TDS.Master\Code Generation Templates\GlassV3Item.tt

Comment: Compiling transformation: Method must have a return type xxx.TDS.Master\Code Generation Templates\GlassV3Item.tt 1

Comment: @DheerajPalagiri: Check GlassV3Header.tt and GlassV3Item.tt and remove any empty lines at the end of the files.

Comment: @jammykam I am sure i removed white spaces and empty lines on all the templates..

Comment: Did you update all the tt's? The latest GlassV3Header.tt file does not contain a reference to HedgehogDevelopment.CodeGeneration.Extensions.dll

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting `HedgehogDevelopment.CodeGeneration.Extensions.dll` error in TDS Sitecore project then put `HedgehogDevelopment.CodeGeneration.Extensions.dll` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` folder for Visual Studio 2012.

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. The TDS installer should be doing this so that TDS is not broken out of the box, but it does not.

Comment: Where can we find the dll?

Answer (score 1):

We just encountered this issue.

There was an empty line at the end of the GlassV3Item.tt file.

Removing that empty line caused the code to be generated successfully.